# Error al iniciar el servidor con php artisan serve en linux centos 6.10 Laravel

Tags: laravel-7

Cuando quiere ejecutar el comando php artisan serve --port=82 --host= IP

Me sale un error de Advertencia de PHP: módulo ya cargado en Desconocido en la línea 0

Ayuda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: intenta reinstalar el imap en centos. Con estos comandos deberias poder hacerlo, luego reinicia su servidor web apache o nginx el que tengas y deberias poder ejecutarlo normal.
yum install epel-release* /
yum install php-imap* / service httpd restart

Comment: Listo lo voy a intentar el orden sería 
1)yum install epel-release
2)yum install php-imap
3)service httpd restart

Comment: considera colocarle el *, pero si esos serian

Comment: No funcionó en cada uno de los comandos me dice que no hay nada por hacer, finalmente vuelvo a iniciar el httpd y me sale el mismo error